# Avverbio di luogo per inciso?

Tags: adverbs, punctuation

Volevo chiedere un parere sulla correttezza della frase "Io, lì, sono andato a vivere per non fare il pendolare." Il mio tentativo era di ricreare un po' il ritmo del parlato, però non sono completamente sicuro che stia grammaticalmente in piedi. Non tanto perché si tratta di un avverbio di luogo, ma perché serve a completare il significato del verbo ("sono andato a vivere lì", "mi sono trasferito lì"). Cosa ne pensate? È una soluzione accettabile?

Comment: A me la frase sembra corretta.

Answer (score 3):

La frase mi sembra perfetta, efficace nel riprodurre un tono colloquiale.

È vero che l'avverbio 'lì' non è nel suo posto più naturale, ma mi sembra un esempio di 'anastrofe', figura retorica che consiste proprio nell'invertire l'ordine naturale della frase, per dare più risalto a un aspetto, in questo caso il tono da lingua parlata.

Mi viene in mente, e mi fa piacere citare, una delle più famose anastrofi della letteratura italiana, Leopardi:

> Sempre caro mi fu quest'ermo colle

Indubbiamente, dire "Quest'ermo colle mi fu sempre caro" sarebbe di una prosaicità deprimente.